# "Undefined type 'App'" in api.php Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm using Laravel 8.53 and Vuejs.
I want to set language for specific controller based on api parameter. (to send password reset email in desired language)
I have this route in `api.php` which works:

```
Route::post('forgot-password', [NewPasswordController::class, 'forgotPassword'])->name('password.reset');
```

Now I wanted to create something like this:

```
Route::post('forgot-password/{locale}', function ($locale) {App::setLocale($locale);}, [NewPasswordController::class, 'forgotPassword'])->name('password.reset');
```

Now when I send to `/api/forgot-password/en` I get `200 OK` but no response.
My VS Code is showing me this error: `Undefined type 'App'`.
Do I need to define "App" in `api.php`? How?

Comment: try this: app()->setLocale($locale)

Comment: Give a \ as `\App::setLocale($locale)`

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it's correlated  but maybe the problem is in different place. You passing three parameters to post method. According to [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/api/master/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Route.html#method_post) you should pass only two. In this case you pass callback, or you pass controller path with method. Try to move `App::setLocale()` to your controller method and use your first syntax. Remember to import `App` facade before using it.

```php
// api.php
Route::post('forgot-password', [NewPasswordController::class, 'forgotPassword'])->name('password.reset');

// NewPasswordController.php
use \App;

class NewPasswordController {
    public function forgotPassword( $locale ) {
         App::setLocale( $locale );

         /* rest of code */
    }
}
```